# String validation

Tags: java, spring, swagger, microservices

I want to validate string to check min and max length and also empty string in swagger

I am able to validate for min and max length but did not find any solution for empty check
null is allowed

```
maxLength: 100
minLength: 70
type: string
example: 'abcddedssk'
x-constraint-messages:
  minLength: ACCOUNT_GUID_MIN_LENGTH
  maxLength: ACCOUNT_GUID_MAX_LENGTH
```

Comment: return s!=null && s.length() >= 70 && s.length()<=100

Answer (score 0):

While I am not entirely sure what Swagger is -- apologies if that is a super common thing and I've been under a rock -- the idea in Java is relatively straight forward.

> Cheng Tao in the comments stated: **return s!=null && s.length() >= 70 && s.length()<=100**

While this works, it uses the concept of Houdini numbers -- or numbers that are included without any reference point. A better way to write this solution would be (IN EXTREME PSEUDO-CODE):

```java
// test 1
if (example != null) 
-> test the length
   // test 2
   if (length >= min && length <= max)
   -> passes

if (either test is not valid) 
-> fails
```

Note that this solution is quite broken down and can be simplified like Tao's solution above.